# Блокировка в чате

Tags: обсуждение, чат, блокировка

Только что получил блокировку на общение в чате на 3 часа, без пояснения причин.
Возникает два вопроса:

- Если мои сообщения нарушали какие-то правила, разве не лучше было бы сообщить об этом?
- Какие правила были нарушены?

Личная просьба от меня, напишите, пожалуйста, в [F# комнате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f), что я напишу ответ при первой возможности. Не хочу, чтобы выглядело будто бы я намеренно игнорирую сообщения другого участника.

Comment: так это была реклама F# комнаты!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Причина блокировки – вредоносный шум, который мешает сообществу сконцентрироваться на решаемой проблеме – миссии проекта, то есть на том, зачем сайт вообще был запущен – создание базы знаний русскоязычного сообщества.

Еще раз подчеркну, что Stack Overflow не является социальной сетью. Да, у нас есть чаты, [наше третье место](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/29/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/). Они полезны во многих случаях, в том числе для «социализации» и нетематических или дискуссионных вопросов. С другой стороны, выплескивание на сообщества неконструктивного негатива недопустимо как на Мете, так и в чате.

Позволю себе [повториться](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38514327#38514327):

> Моя личная рекомендация всем участникам, которые пришли на сайт для того, чтобы либо делиться знаниями, либо их получать – пожалуйста, игнорируйте всех тех, кто пытается втянуть вас в словесную баталию, выяснения отношений или «крутости» или чего–либо аналогичного. Думаю, мы все с вами понимаем, что в «интернет–дуэлях» нет победителей, есть только проигравшие – те, кто провел свой день не самым лучшим из возможных способов.

Задача [управляющего](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/) – помощь сообществу в самоопределении, выборе оптимального пути развития и в поддержании траектории движения к цели. Во много большей мере чем управляющий, сообществу в этом помогают [выбранные модераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

Как мне кажется, если кто–либо будет нарушать правила, первоочередная задача управляющего или модераторов – оградить сообщество от нарушителя.

Отвечая на ваш вопрос, опять же [повторюсь](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38514033#38514033):

> Модераторы сайта – не судьи. Чат и Мета – это не площадка для драматургии, сочинений на вольную тему или чего–либо еще. Здесь не «первый канал». Это сайт вопросов и ответов по программированию, цель которого – снижение вредоносного шума. Вся не конструктивная драма, вне зависимости от того, кто прав, кто виноват и что надо было делать, будет удалена.

Прошу обратить внимание на то, [что](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38514099#38514099)

> Идеологию сайта и допустимость как поведения, так и тем для рассмотрения вы можете найти в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) и в вопросах с меткой [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: опять таки это не ответ на поставленный вопрос. Почему нельзя просто написать перед блокировкой - "если вы продолжите обсуждать здесь эту тему, то вы получите блокировку на N дней"?

Comment: @FoggyFinder На сайте нет личных сообщений, по указанной в ответе выше причине, то есть при блокировке в чате, если я что–то не упустил, я не могу что–либо вам написать.

Comment: "На сайте нет личных сообщений, по указанной в ответе выше причине, то есть при блокировке в чате, если я что–то не упустил, я не могу что–либо вам написать." извините, я не понял вашего сообщения. Я имею ввиду написать публично

Comment: @FoggyFinder Сообщения, направленные на выяснения отношений и того, кто, что и кому сказал вносят вредоносный ненужный шум.

Comment: @FoggyFinder На мой взгляд, я не раз подчеркнул, что рассмотрение «социальных аспектов» в том виде, как это было в вашем случае, противоречит тому, что бы участники хотели видеть, как минимум, в общей комнате сообщества. Сожалению, что я не смог выразить данный факт в более явной форме.

Comment: извините, но вы никак не дали это понять, вы продолжали отвечать на мои вопросы а затем просто заблокировали когда вам это надело. Таким образом вы вначале _как будто_ дали понять, что подобные обсуждения допустимы. Но, спасибо, я понял вашу точку зрения и политику сообщества в целом, в дальнейшем в подобных обсуждениях принимать участие не буду.

Comment: Никакой конкретики, "вредоносный шум" -- слишком абстрактное понятие. Не могли бы вы привести _конкретные вырезки_ из чата, которые по вашему мнению не соответствуют принятым правилам сообщества, таким образом подкрепив свой ответ некоторыми доказательствами?

Comment: @Nikita «вредоносный шум» – это все, что не относится к программированию. Для чата, на мой взгляд, это понятие чуть чуть шире и допускает общение на около тематические для конкретного чата темы. При этом, любая ругань или не конструктивная критика крайне мешает как сосредоточиться на решаемой проблеме, так и создать дружелюбную, «безопасную» атмосферу для свободного высказывания своих мыслей и идей.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky  Понятия "жизнь", "люди", "уважение" не относиться напрямую к программированию (так как программирование это инструмент, а ни цель ), но при этом пронизывают его (программирование). Выходит _в моём понимании_ что всё не является программированием . Либо любая не понравившаяся фраза модератору может быть подведена под понятие «вредоносный шум», так ли это ?? Есть ли стандартизация либо описание понятия  «вредоносный шум» ?? Спасибо. С уважением, считаю ваш труд весьма сложным и важным :3