# Бан чата, 14.01.2018

Tags: поддержка, чат

Я написал в чате:

> @PashaPash а я врублю @NicolasChabanovsky, и отвечу "Вы - модератор, Вы сами должны понимать когда грубите человеку"

и получил:

> your account has been automatically suspended for posting [inappropriate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/42271737/history) content and cannot chat for 29 minutes.

Пожалуйста, объясните что тут "inappropriate".

Comment: Очевидно, что блокировка была за [вредоносный шум](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5554/Блокировка-в-чате)

Comment: `automatically` же?

Answer (score 5):

Вообще, вполне разумно, что многие не хотели бы быть мной (как и я многими). Я рад и приятно удивлен, что подобные ситуации, где чей–либо «персонаж» используют определенно как коннотацию к негативному действию, сообщество отмечает оскорбительным, чем оно и является.

Если бы я увидел, что кто–либо использует ваш псевдоним в качестве термина, с отрицательным значением, я бы тоже использовал сигнал тревоги.

Answer (score -1):

Вы начали в достаточно грубой манере требовать "пруфов", называть модератора демагогом, давайть ссылки на статьи "Пассивно-агрессивное поведение" в вики.

> Грубость и оскорбления – это плохо. Тон ваших сообщений должен быть таким же, как при разговоре с тем, кого вы уважаете и от кого ждёте встречного уважения.

Я понимаю, что вы огорчены тем, что администрацией были отменены выбранные [владельцы комнаты в чате](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6713/), но напоминаю вам, что [все участники должны использовать профессиональный и цивилизованный подход в общении на наших сайтах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice/).

Comment: Не является ответом, в вопросе написано `объясните что тут "inappropriate".`

Comment: @Abyx на мой взгляд, в ответе прямо написано, почему ваши сообщения inappropriate - они прямо нарушают правила в части be nice. я даже процитировал справку, на случай если ссылки окажется недостаточно.

Comment: Я правильно понял, кто когда Вам не нравится содержимое сообщения участника, Вы объявляете что форма сообщения нарушает Be Nice и баните участника?

Comment: @Abyx нет, вы поняли неправильно.