# Анализ тревог в чате за последние 30*6 дней от 15 января 2018

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

В последнее время в сообществе было очень много разговоров относительно тревог в чате, в частности, что участники сообщества получают незаслуженные блокировки как результат неверной проверки выполненной нашими русско не говорящими коллегами. Давайте попробуем разобраться, так ли это, взглянув на цифры.

<sub>Анализ ниже сделан в полу автоматическом режиме в связи с достаточно сложной для автоматического анализа схемой базы данных чатов. Анализ сделан 15 января 2018 года за последние 30*6 дней</sub>

- Всего 78 сообщений были отмечены тревогами: 12 — требует внимания модератора, 66 — оскорбления или спам.
- Из них было удалено 17: 5 — требует внимания модератора, 12 — оскорбления или спам.

#### Удаление сообщений и блокировки

Заметьте, что удалено оно может быть кем угодно, и как угодно. В базе я вижу лишь факт удаления. Насколько я понимаю, единственный способ, когда автор сообщения получает блокировку в чате — удаление сообщение через подтверждение тревоги. Также, насколько я понимаю, когда сообщение удаляется по тревоге, автором удаления выступает «Feeds». Я задал уточняющий вопрос коллегам. Если будет обновление, я сразу же отпишусь.

Таким образом, меня волновало два аспекта:

1. получил ли участник блокировку, то есть сообщение было удалено «не Feeds»;
2. участвовал ли в проверке нерусскоговорящий коллега (не говорящего на русском я определяю как человека, без активности на каком–либо сайте на русском языке).

**Удаленные сообщения, требующие внимания модератора** (всего 5 сообщений)

- Удалено нерусскоговорящим модератором модератором: 3
- Удалено русскоговорящим модератором: 1
- Удалено с последующей блокировкой автора (те удалял Feeds): 1

**Удаленные сообщения, отмеченные как спам или оскорбления** (всего 12 сообщений)

- Удалено нерусскоговорящим участником: 1
- Удалено русскоговорящим участником: 6
- Удалено с последующей блокировкой автора (т.е. удалял Feeds):

  - Интернациональный состав: 2
  - Только русскоязычные участники: 1
  - Только нерусскоговорящие участники: 2

**Вывод:** я не вижу, чтобы в случае участия в проверке коллег, которые не знают русский язык, данные как–то шокирующие выделялись. Я не вижу подтверждению словам, что система тревог сломана, что контекст нашей культуры не понять.

**Важное замечание.** В статистике выше не было данных по сообщениям, удаленным тревогой модератора. Я вижу у модераторов Stack Overflow на русском 37 действий выставления тревоги или обработки тревоги на сообщениях в чате, из которых в 20 случаях сообщения были удалены.

#### Ирония

Также в чате был поднят вопрос иронии. Допустима ли она? Если да, то удаляться ли?

Я просмотрел сообщения, которые были отмечены сигналом тревоги, на предмет наличия в них «иронии». В самом широком смысле этого слова, я подобрал следующее:

- «Не всех. Оскорблять тут нельзя только иностранцев.»
- «сейчас еще иностранный десант наспаунится»
- «а Вы сегодня дёргали уже?»
- «за гугл транслейт наверн»
- «сколько секунд осталось до падения ---чёрного ястреба--- чата?»
- «Вот интересно, а если писающего мальчика на аватарку поставить - это сразу бан или нет?»
- «Подтверждение того, что все модераторы - хамьё! :)»
- «устроим свой Winter bash ... с флагами ⚑»

Обратите внимание, ни одно из этих сообщений удалено не было. Ни по тревоге, ни руками. Из них проверено русскоязычными участниками: 1, нерусскоязычными: 7.

<sub>Мне лично, часть этих сообщений видеть не приятно. Часть я вообще не понимаю, зачем и к чему сказано. Вот совсем, вообще, не нахожу связи высказывания с контекстом.</sub>

**Вывод:** это миф, что иностранные коллеги не могут или не хотят понять иронию и контекст на русском языке. Люди по большей степени ответственно подходят к проверке.

#### Пример обработки тревоги

Мне показалось очень интересным для понимания проблемы, посмотреть, как выглядят данные для какой–нибудь тревоги. Как мне подсказали коллеги, у нас есть следующая формула: `EffectiveFlags = Flags - CounterFlags - Unsure/5`. Далее происходит одно из двух:

1. Если `EffectiveFlags` достигает 6 (или получает подтверждение от модератора), сообщение удаляется.
2. Если `EffectiveFlags` опускается ниже 0, все тревоги в ожидании для сообщения отклоняются.

Что же происходит с сообщением? Например, возьмем удаленное сообщение «бога НЕТ!». Пожалуйста, воспринимайте это не более как пример сообщения, которому в чате не место. Оно взято как типичный пример и очень важно для понимания процессов, происходящих в системе тревог. Согласно истории, сообщение удалил я. Автор не получил блокировку: я отклонил тревогу перед удалением, удалял вручную. Что интересно, в обработке сообщения приняли участие 17 человек (плюс автор тревоги, плюс я). В том числе:

- Иностранных участников, подтвердивших тревогу: 1
- Иностранных участников, отклонивших тревогу: -
- Иностранных участников, не уверенных в тревоге: 14
- Русскоязычных участников, подтвердивших тревогу: -
- Русскоязычных участников, отклонивших тревогу: 1
- Русскоязычных участников, не уверенных в тревоге: 1

**Вывод:** Опять же, я не вижу, чтобы иностранные коллеги нажимали «случайную кнопку». Если они что–то не понимают, они так и поступают — жмут «unsure».

#### Другие идеи для проверок

Пожалуйста, дайте знать, если вы считаете, что нам надо посмотреть на другие параметры системы тревог.

Comment: Вообще, хотелось бы более детальную информацию по голосам.

Comment: То есть TL;DR - иностранцы нам не "мешают", ирония вызывает флаги, но не наказуема. Примерно так?

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, поясните, что именно вы понимаете под «детальной информацией»?

Comment: @Kromster Да, я не вижу в данных подтверждения гипотезы о невнимании или нежелании разобраться в контексте сообщений с тревогами со стороны наших иностранных коллег. Про иронию я вас не понял. Не могли бы вы более развернуто написать, что имеется в виду?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вот как ты тревогу «бога НЕТ!» расписал сделать столюбцы (только добавить ещё колонки для действий модераторов), а 78 тревог - в строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это сложно сделать сейчас, поскольку каждого участвующего надо рассматривать вручную (описание о себе, место жительства, наличие вопросов на сайтах с русским языком), чтобы понять, считать ли его «иностранцем» или нет. Более того, сама сводка предлагаемой вами таблицы, уже дана сейчас. Подскажите, или я не верно вас понял?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вот такую таблицу на 78 строк: https://jsfiddle.net/62o67jLu/ Хм.. тип тревоги ещё добавить туда: https://jsfiddle.net/62o67jLu/1/

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а прям в базе поджойнить таблицы соответствующем образом не выйдет? Чтоб получилось `сообщение тип-тревоги участник число-сообщений-на-русскоязычных-сайтах действие является-ли-модератором` - вроде из этого легко строится нужная таблица?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не знаю, как автоматически достоверно определять русскоязычный это участник или нет. Можно, конечно, эвристиками. К примеру, есть люди, которые не взаимодействуют на русскоязычных сайтах, но из РФ. Есть проживающие в Британии, но с ответами на Russian.SE с кириллицей в ответах. Есть еще несколько технических моментов, почему я делал это в «полуавтоматическим режиме». Сделать то, что вы запрашиваете сейчас мне видится несколько трудоемким и подверженным большому количеству допущенных ошибок, если делать вручную.

Comment: @Qwertiy С другой стороны, подскажите, что нам это даст? Понимание каких процессов изменится или станет более верным?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я бы русскоязычных определял по наличию сообщений или комментариев на одном из русскоязычных сайтов.

Comment: Приведённая формула не различает, чьи там были голоса. Т. е. по отклонённым тревогам не понятно, были они отклонены из-за того, что в чате было достаточно русскоязычного народу до того, как набежали внешние (но несколько из них всё же успели проголосовать), или же все действительно голосуют соответствующим образом. Поэтому и хочется статистику в духе "В ?% случаев русские голоса успеваю перевесить иностранные".

Comment: @Qwertiy На сколько я могу знать (могу ошибаться тут!), у нас базы сайтов раздельные, а еще отдельна база чатов. И id чата различается даже от id SE. Чаты еще к разным учеткам привязаны (у кого–то к SE, у кого–то к конкретному сайту). Не говоря о том, что я не видел никакой доки на этот счет. Чтобы составить подобный запрос, надо недели две точно потратить, думаю. То есть если садиться, то надо на все остальное забить и дать мне время. Но! Я могу подобное сделать для нескольких сообщений вручную.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71851/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-nicolas-chabanovsky).

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю с математикой. Каждый день удаляется по 5 сообщений, умножаем на 6 месяцев - и получаем... 15?

Comment: Кто в таком случае удалял сообщения в чате? Авторы самостоятельно? RO? Модераторы?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Подскажите, где вы взяли цифру 5?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky из памяти, по ощущениям. Каждый день в чате я видел пропавшие сообщения. В течении долгого периода времени. Это работало так: свернул чат чтобы поработать, развернул - а там куча пропавших строчек. Или все что-то весело обсуждают, а обсуждаемое сообщение удалено...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky пруфов привести не могу по понятным причинам - они все удалены.

Comment: @PavelMayorov насколько я понимаю здесь речь идет об удаленных сообщениях на которые стояли флаги

Comment: @FoggyFinder дело в том, что я думал (и предполагаю что не только я) что проблема чата во флагах потому что пропадали сообщения. Но если сообщения пропадали не из-за флагов - это означает что проблема осталась, только теперь непонятно в чем же она заключается.

Comment: @PavelMayorov на мой взгляд есть две проблемы. 1. флаги которые ставят без должной причины 2. удаление сообщений которые считаются [вредоносным шумом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5554/Блокировка-в-чате)

Comment: @PavelMayorov "Кто в таком случае удалял сообщения в чате? Авторы самостоятельно? RO? Модераторы?" Возможность удалять сообщения есть только у модераторов. Автор может удалить свое сообщение самостоятельно, но только в течении очень небольшого периода времени (могу ошибаться, но кажется он составляет 2 минуты). RO могут только перемещать сообщения.

Comment: я думал реально больше чем 15 блокировок. я сам лично 2 раза на полчаса попал :)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что из 78 флагнутых сообщений большинство ложные флаги? Только 15 удалены, остальное фланнуто в шутку? То есть флаги используются не по назначению. Можно ли флаги по датам сгруппировать: они равномерно идут или плотно пошли начиная с месяц тому назад? Какие меры применяются к тем, кто флагает зря?

Comment: @pavel Если быть точным, у вас три блокировки было.

Comment: @AK Не совсем верно. Из 78 тревог, в результате было удалено 15 сообщений, причем как с подтверждением тревоги (случай блокировки), так и с отклонением тревоги (удаление вручную). Можно ли считать оставшиеся тревоги ложными — вопрос спорный (я бы сказал субъективный). Можно говорить лишь, что тревоги были отклонены.

Comment: @AK был один день когда многие участники (в том числе и я ставили флаги для фана). Если флагов всего 78 (думал, что за год их будет явно больше), то предположу что основной пик был в тот день + еще 2-3 пика поменьше, а остальное - равномерно.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Пожалуйста, не искажайте действительность. Многие участники — это сколько? К примеру, вы один или вдвоем с кем–то — это уже многие? Также, почему если вы использовали сигнал тревоги шутки ради, вы решили, что и другие так делали, а не использовали его по делу?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "Пожалуйста, не искажайте действительность." пожалуйста, не надо ложных обвинений. "Многие участники — это сколько?" Многие это как минимум 5. "Также, почему если вы использовали сигнал тревоги шутки ради, вы решили, что и другие так делали, а не использовали его по делу?" Это было весело и смешно, приведу [ссылку](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41293862#41293862) на историю чата того дня, о котором идет речь в предыдущем сообщении.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Если хотите я могу удалить предыдущие комментарии и убрать эмоциональную окраску, оставив только предположение: Подозреваю, что максимальный пик был [22 ноября](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41293862#41293862) и еще пару пиков поменьше, по остальным дням - равномерно.

Comment: А я подожду точные цифры и графики.

Comment: @AK согласен - графики нагляднее и точнее покажут. (я ведь только предполагаю по ощущением а это не всегда надежно)

Comment: @FoggyFinder, по ссылке на всей странице удалено одно сообщение, удалено чужим модератором. Текст удалённого сообщения: `давайте эксперимент. я отменяю предыдущее сообщение про баны - флаги разрешены.`

Comment: @Qwertiy не уверен, что понимаю почему вы мне это говорите

Comment: @FoggyFinder, потому что в твоём комментарии [ссылка](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41293862#41293862) на страницу архива чата - это про неё.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, но я ее привел в качестве ответа на вопрос A K про равномерность распределения флагов. Тогда флаги ставились на сообщения в которых не было ничего плохого - просто ради эксперимента. Но даже хорошо что об этом упомянули - как раз пример неправильной проверки.

Comment: Я ожидал что-то вроде таймлайна к каждому флагнутому сообщению. Например, `2017.11.11T20:30, user123: "за гугл транслейт наверн". юзер10 флагнул, юзер20 - за, юзер30 - против, мод1 - против, флаг отклонен.` "юзер123" обеспечит анонимность, но при этом позволит понять количество участвовавших в флагфесте. А суммы посчитать - это мы уже сами можем сделать.

Comment: @Abyx Представьте, что в вашем коллективе з/п рассчитывают на основе _анонимных_ отзывов коллег. Все всегда было хорошо, но вдруг кто–то выставил всем отрицательные оценки. Вы говорите, что это все не честно и просите показать историю анонимных оценок. Я ситуацию вижу именно так. Конечно, я уточню у коллег, что они думаю про эту затею, но мне она не кажется правильной.

Comment: @Abyx Уточнил. Коллеги также против. Система анонимная за исключением тревог «требует внимания модератора», в которой, опять же, только модератор видит автора тревоги.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но таймлайн хотя-бы можно добавить?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я не говорю что надо писать имена, наоборот, я хочу заменить имена на "Person A", "Person B"

Comment: @Abyx когда вы говорите про id участника, именно так я и понимаю. Подскажите, что вы хотите выяснить такой статистикой? Как мне казалось, мы хотим разобраться в справедливости обработки тревог русскоговорящих и тех, кто русский язык не знает (хотя, это по определению субъективное решение и мы не знаем, как понял сообщение конкретный участник). Единственный вариант — рассматривать тревоги в контексте самого сообщения (как это сделано в примере). На первый взгляд, предлагаемая к рассмотрению таблица не добавит никакого понимания.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Интересная информация. Тогда как вы объясните шквал тревог? Мы для начала хотим выяснить, кто виноват в этом шквале. // Вы получили моё письмо? Ваше мне пришлось вытаскивать из подозрительных на спам.

Comment: @VladD Я получил ваше письмо, спасибо! Буквально час назад дописал и отправил ответ! Я не знаю хороших инструментов, которые помогли бы нам создать причинно–следственную связь с высокой точностью (кто его знает на что именно кто–то среагировал с какой задержкой, как понял сообщение). Я не пытался искать «виноватого», как минимум, подобных просьб пока не звучало. Все же, в письме я рискнул высказать предположение, взяв в рассмотрение несколько точек зрения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Спасибо, я почитаю вечером.

Comment: Написано, что удаленных как «спам» 10, но сумма 1+6+2+1+2 = 12. Где ошибка? Еще мне не понятно, кто такие участники в этом списке, когда речь не про Feeds. Кто-то сам удалял свои сообщения, или речь о модераторах, удаляющих без блокировки?

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо за замечание! Поправил!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky второй вопрос до сих пор не раскрыт.

Comment: @alexolut Участники — это участники. Кто угодно. И авторы сообщений, и модераторы нашего сайта, и модераторы не из нашего сообщества.

Comment: Что по поводу таймлайна?

Comment: `Удаленные сообщения, требующие внимания модератора` — что-то (одна-две) из этих тревог были моими, на собственные сообщения. Поступал так, если не укладывался с правками в grace period (пока не получил блокировку за длинную историю подобных самотревог, тянущуюся ещё с Политоты, и не понял, что автоматика не проверяет флагающего и флагаемого на совпадение. После этого пришлось оставлять сообщения как есть).

Comment: @Arhad  Я частенько вижу тревоги «требует внимания модератора» на свои сообщения из других сообществ. Если вы укажите, что вам надо лишь удалить старое сообщение, обычно модератор так и сделает. Блокировать в этом случае никого не должны :)